# How can I unit test that I received correct PreparedStatement?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

I want to pass in suitable object into the verify method, not just any().

Is there a way to do it?

I cannot just take and copy Lambda method and pass the results into the verify. That doesn't work because Lambdas cannot be tested directly.

My Unit test which is obviously not even close to testing anything:

```
    @Test
public void testRunTrigger() {
    campaignTrigger.updateCampaignStatus();

    verify(jdbcTemplate).update(any(PreparedStatementCreator.class));
    assertEquals("UPDATE campaign SET state = 'FINISHED'  WHERE state IN ('PAUSED','CREATED','RUNNING') AND campaign_end < ? ", campaignTrigger.UPDATE_CAMPAIGN_SQL);
}
```

And  this is the class I'm testing :

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class CampaignTrigger {
final String UPDATE_CAMPAIGN_SQL = String.format("UPDATE campaign SET state = '%s' " +
                " WHERE state IN (%s) AND campaign_end < ? ", FINISHED,
        Stream.of(PAUSED, CREATED, RUNNING)
                .map(CampaignState::name)
                .collect(Collectors.joining("','", "'", "'")));

@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Scheduled(cron = "${lotto.triggers.campaign}")
@Timed
void updateCampaignStatus() {
    jdbcTemplate.update(con -> {
        PreparedStatement callableStatement = con.prepareStatement(UPDATE_CAMPAIGN_SQL);
        callableStatement.setTimestamp(1,  Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now()));
        log.debug("Updating campaigns statuses.");
        return callableStatement;
    });
}
```

Any advice, or theoretical knowledge that this is not the way to do it I would highly appreciate.

Comment: You could check that `con.prepareStatement(UPDATE_CAMPAIGN_SQL)` and `callableStatement.setTimestamp(1,  Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now()))` were called with the appropriate parameters...

Comment: Could you please provide more details how can I go about that?

Comment: That kind of depends whether `con` is a mock or not. At the same time, thinking a second time, capturing the argument when calling the mocked `JdbcTemplate`, as @GhostCat suggested, is way clearer and elegant

Comment: No, it's not a mock :( . Yea, it's a nice way but all I get is CampaignTrigger$$Lambda$6/103536485@1e67a849 object, can't seem to access insides of it.

Comment: You're right, there's not much to see as it's an implementation of the `PreparedStatementCreator` interface. Breaking down the responsibilities,  `updateCampaignStatus` should be calling `jdbcTemplate.update` with a specific implementation of `PreparedStatementCreator`. If you had 2 distinct classes you could check individually that your `PreparedStatementCreator` is generating the desired `PreparedStatement` and that `jdbcTemplate` is called with that particular creator. Since it's all _inline_ I don't really see what you can do besides my initial suggestion (I know, I changed my mind twice)

Comment: Furthermore, `JdbcTemplate` seems to be a mock in your code, so I'm not sure how the provided `con` can be real, unless you manually specified one. Anyway, pursuing this road kind of means mocking the spring behaviour and you'd be doing what Jaroslaw is saying in his answer below. With all this in mind, if I were you, I'd extract that lambda into its own class, and test the 2 separately in isolation. Any other suggestions are more than welcome.

Comment: "Test behaviour, not implementation". What you want to test is that the column in your table is updated (and probably that the log happens). Whether it is done via `jdbcTemplate.update(PreparedStatementCreator)` or via `jdbcTemplate.update(String)` does not matter. Do test driven development and write your test before the implementation - you won't face such problems. Now you are just trying to freeze your code - so the test fails if any Java statement in your code changes, even if it still does the job. That's not the purpose of testing and it will cause you a lot of maintenance pain later.

Comment: I want to thank you @Morfic for your input. It's always nice to hear some thoughts about my code. Next time I run into similar task I will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't mock the code which you don't control. Mock only the code for which you have your tests, because when mocking you are assuming that you know (i.e. you define) how the mocked class works.

Here, you have no idea how `jdbcTemplate` works and whether calling it with some lambda actually does what you think it does.

Testing your code with code that you don't control is the point of integration tests. I.e. you should test your `CampaignTrigger` together with a real database (or in-memory one) and without mocking `jdbcTemplate`.

Comment: I agree about mocking the external system behaviour, but I see no harm in using mocks for it in your unit test checking that the interactions with that systems match your expectations, eg `verify(mockConnection).prepareStatement(expectedSQL)`. This allows to have some unit tests (which should be quick) running before committing, besides the integration ones (which are usually slow) that are executed only once in a while.

Comment: I'd also appreciate your input regarding the latest comments if possible.

Comment: @Morfic The question is about the value of such unit test. Does it fail faster than integration test? Sure. But is it going to fail if some code beyond our control changes? Unlikely. So all we get is pain in maintaining extra tests, because whenever you change your integration tests, you need to change unit tests - you need to spend sometimes a few hours on this, to save you a couple of seconds on each build. Integration tests should be fast, they don't require application to start. If they are slow, adding unit tests on top of integration tests doesn't sound like a good solution.

Comment: I can recommend you "Growing Object Oriented Software Guided by Tests" by Steve Freeman and Nat Pryce for further reading. Generally, a class should have either a unit test or an integration test, never both. Otherwise we also have different kind of high level black-box acceptance testing which should also cover majority of happy paths in our code.

Comment: Well, I meant _latest comments below the question_, sorry for not being specific. And thanks for the suggestion, I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak Thanks for the answer and the recommendation. I will certainly, take a look at that book.

Answer (score 3):

You could try your luck with **capturing** the object that is used for that call, see [here](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.7.19/org/mockito/Mockito.html#15). That allows to write code like this:

```
ArgumentCaptor<Person> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Person.class);
verify(mock).doSomething(argument.capture());
assertEquals("John", argument.getValue().getName());
```

Giving you **full** access to the object that was passed to your method call! And note that mockito recently introduced a @Captor annotation that makes things even easier to use.

Edit; given the comments by @Morfic: what he states is absolutely reasonable.

This answer is giving the "immediate" hint how you could solve that specific problem.

Beyond: the reasonable approach is always always always to slice that "unit under test" ... to be as small as possible!

Your class/method(s) should serve exactly one responsibility; and then you makes sure that the implementation can be tested with most simple means possible.

So: if the question is: "should I use argument captors or should I better rework my production code" - then rework your production code.

Comment: Since you're part of this and I've been quoting your answer, would you join the comments section if you have the time? :-)

Comment: @GhostCat Thanks for your answer, I tried but no luck. Although, I have never used ArgumentCaptor, was nice to see it in action. And yea, I got the point from other comments/answers I need to do some reworking on the code. Next time, I will keep it in mind.

Comment: It is always good to learn something. And that is true for all folks around here ;-)